# Lexer predicate for XPath 3 comments

Tags: parsing, antlr4, xpath-3.0

I am trying to implement an XPath 3 parser in Antlr 4. In the EBNF given in the XPath specification it makes use of `-` to indicate that something should be excluded, if I understand correctly, then in Antlr I can use a predicate instead to achieve the same behaviour.

I am struggling with implementing `CommentContents` from the EBNF, as I am not quite sure how to construct the predicate. This is what I have so far:

```
/** [2] Char ::= [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
 *
 * //any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF
 */
 Char : '\u0001'..'\uD7FF' | '\uE000'..'\uFFFD' | '\u10000'..'\u10FFFF' ;


/** [108] CommentContents ::= (Char+ - (Char* ('(:' | ':)') Char*)) */
CommentContents : Char+ { $Char+.text.indexOf("(:") + $Char+.text.indexOf(":)") == 0  } ;
```

Can someone confirm if I have the predicate for `CommentContents` correct so that it matches the intention of the EBNF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need {...}? not {...}. Also $Char+.text won't work.  I suggest making Java function that does the test, returning boolean then just call it.

Comment: Okay, I may be being a bit dumb here! If I cannot use $Char+ as a reference to the current Lexer tokens, so that I have the current context to make a decision, what should I use as the argument to my Java function?

Comment: In this case, you just pass getText() ($getText? can remember) to the function and then have it check the prefix of the string.